Why is `mv -f source target` so much slower than `rm -f target && mv source target`
I got a case where I need to overwrite some file with another and noticed a very significant slowdown when using "mv -f" if the target already exists and is being read. More specifically, the folder is also mounted as a network drive under Windows and when I select the target file in the explorer with file preview on, the mv command takes sometimes up to 15 seconds to complete.
If I instead rename the target to something else first or just delete it (rm -f) and then mv the whole thing is basically instant.
Why is removing the file and then writing where it used to be so much faster and why is the overwriting even taking so long in the first place?

Edit:
I got a situation like this:
/data/file-a.png should be moved to /data/file-b.png overwriting anything that is there. /data/ is a normal local folder AFAIK.
This operation is happening on a linux server, on a folder that is shared somehow (I don't really know how) with a Windows Client (that I am on) as a Network-Drive. This Drive is hosted on the Linux Server, so for the Server it should be an easy operation I feel like.
Anyways.
I run the command mv -f /data/file-a.png /data/file-b.png via ssh on the Linux server, shortly after selecting file-b.png on the network drive with preview on.
When I do that, the command just takes between 10 and 15 seconds to complete.
If I instead move file-b.png somewhere else or just remove it before using mv the command finishes basically instant and the windows network drive also gets updated very quickly, unselecting the file I had selected (since that was moved/removed and then replaced).

Are you moving the file within a single filesystem or across filesystems? What filesystems are they? How is the directory being shared to the Windows host? What  OS are you on?

What client system are you using? Windows with Cygwin? WSL? Some sort of VM? From what type of system is the filesystem being shared to you? Over SMB (or NFS, or sshfs, or...)?

Both comments above are correct in analysis.  If you just want it to go away, don't use DHCP.  Set static IP's.  The windows network folder will open like it's a regular directory, the difference is instantly noticeable.  If that doesn't solve it, it's a middleware issue, not the network.

"If I instead rename the target"; but mv renames; under the hood there is a rename C function that it uses.

Is the -f option a red herring here? Might the rm operation be speeding up the subsequent mv regardless of the -f in mv?  The -f should only be disabling the interactive prompting. If anything, that should make mv faster, because it can just try the operation rather than checking for the existence of something in order to generate a prompt.

Thanks for the help. I added some clarifications.
@kaz I know mv renames. I meant if I move whatever is at the location, I want to overwrite, away from there before doint mv -f to that target. That way the mv command doesn't need to overwrite anything, it just needs to move a file. I could ommit the -f for the mv but then it would prompt me if I wanted to overwrite the file, which I always want to in these cases.
